# Antiderivative of an interpolation function(NDSolveValue)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Given an examplary simple interpolation function `U[t,x]`

```
U = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] ==  D[u[t, x], {x, 2}],u[0, x] == Sin[Pi x], u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I would like to derive the antiderivative of `\[CurlyPhi][x]`

```
\[CurlyPhi] =Function[x, Derivative[0, 1][U][0, x] - Derivative[1, 0 ][U][0, x] ]
Plot[\[CurlyPhi][x], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[CurlyPhi][x]"}]
```

[image]

But

```
 \[Phi] = Evaluate[Derivative  [-1][\[CurlyPhi] ][x]]
```

unfortunately doesn't evaluate.

What' s wrong with this attempt?
Thanks!

**addendum**

Interestingly basically `Derivative[-1]...` works in this example

```
cos = FunctionInterpolation[Cos[u], {u, 0, Pi}]
Plot[{cos[x], Derivative[-1][cos][x]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

without problems as expected.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, yes there are several alternatives. I would like to understand why `Derivative[-1]..` fails in case of an expression containing several interpolation-functions whereas it works for a single interpolation function

Comment: This succeeds, `Block[{U}, Integrate[Derivative[0, 1][U][0, x] - Derivative[1, 0][U][x, 0], x]]`, but the original integral fails `Block[{U}, 
 Integrate[Derivative[0, 1][U][0, x] - Derivative[1, 0][U][0, x], x]]` on the `Integrate` level, regardless of whether `U` is an interpolating function or not.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, but this workaround has nothing left with the original question. It seems the two arguments in the `U-function` cause the problems!

Comment: It was not meant as a workaround. I was responding to "What' s wrong with this attempt?", which does not even ask for a workaround. I was pointing out one of a couple obstructions, namely `Integrate`/`Derivative[-1]` itself even if `U` is an abstract function. (Another is that they do not operation on multivariate interpolation functions. And another you've already pointed out, that they do not operate on interpolating functions in more complicated expressions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using another NDSolve?

```
ad = y /. 
   First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == \[CurlyPhi][x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}];

Plot[ad[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Is this what you need?

**Edit**

I have just found that `FunctionInterpolation` works

```
f1 = FunctionInterpolation[\[CurlyPhi][x], {x, 0, 1}];
f2 = Derivative[-1][f1];
```

However, it does throw an error. I don't know if I trust `FunctionInterpolation` to take enough steps. It might be better to extract the steps from your original function and re-interpolate using those. I seem to remember that Mathematica development was slow to make `Interpolation` work as other functions. `Integrate` is still an issue.

Comment: Thank you for that workaround. Usually `Derivative[-1][...` does the same result, but not in the case I aksed for.

Comment: Is `Derivative[-1][... ` documented?  I know derivatives work but had no idea the antiderivative could work.

Comment: Yes, I think it is. See documentation "Derivative[-n][f] represents the n ^th indefinite integral of f. "

Comment: Thanks for your helpful edit